# Confusion in Training Logistic Regression Model

Tags: regression, logistic, loss-functions

I have a confusion in Cost function in Logistic Regression, I have a set of data

```
Cond.1 <- c(2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7,
        3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.6,
        4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7)

Cond.2 <- c(2.3, 2.4, 2.6, 3.1, 3.7, 3.7, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.8, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.7,
        5.8, 5.9, 5.9, 6.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.1, 6.3, 6.5, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1,
        7.2, 7.2, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.6, 10, 10.1, 12.5)
```

and I have used logistic regression to plot this data

```
lr.model = glm(ind~values+I(values^2), dat, family="binomial")
lr.preds = predict(lr.model, type="response")
ord      = order(dat$values)
dat      = dat[ord,]
lr.preds = lr.preds[ord]

windows()
  with(dat, plot(values, ifelse(ind=="cond2",1,0), 
             ylab="predicted probability of condition2"))
  lines(dat$values, lr.preds)
```

[image]

Now, I want to apply a Loss function to it. 
I dont know how to train the model or how to get h(x) (hypothesis/response surface or the predicted values).

I also saw somewhere that in Logistical Regression

> *h=log(p/(1-p))*

where P is probability +ve outcome. If that is true then the predicted values are comming from 'test data'.

I have a confusion here,

How to train the model?

If h(x) is comming from test data then is there need to train the model ?

If not, then how to get training data?

I have 39 observations in each condition, if I train the model with 20 and test it with 19, will it be wise or I have less data?

Comment: Could you write down the exact model you are working with based on the data that you provided?

Comment: @RustyStatistician, I have used Logisic regression to model the data.

Comment: Oh I understand that.  I guess what I meant is can we reproduce the analysis (i.e., the plot) that you created? In your data set, is `Cond.1` the output variable and `Cond.2` the predictor variable?  Or....?

Comment: @RustyStatistician, I have updated the question with the code to reproduce the analysis.